# Odoo - Service not starting

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I use to work on ubuntu server for Odoo10e and following are few commands which i usually use.

```
sudo service odoo stop
sudo service odoo start
sudo service odoo status
sudo service odoo restart
```

I install pysftp using CLI and then executed command `sudo service odoo restart` but now i am seeing `Service Unavailable` when i try to access it from url. But when i try to get info from CLI `sudo service odoo status`
is showing following result.

```
● odoo.service - LSB: Start odoo daemon at boot time
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/odoo; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-07-25 13:07:41 UTC; 7min ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
     CPU: 0

Jul 25 13:07:41 ip-10-10-0-84 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start odoo daemon at boot time...
Jul 25 13:07:41 ip-10-10-0-84 odoo[3070]: Starting odoo: ok
Jul 25 13:07:41 ip-10-10-0-84 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start odoo daemon at boot time.
Jul 25 13:15:04 ip-10-10-0-84 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start odoo daemon at boot time.
```

Comment: Can you able to run with manual commands without script ? If yes, then might be issue with script.

Comment: i don't even know how to run with manual command.

Comment: your service should locate in /etc/init.d/. If you look at the odoo service in an editor you should be able to find the commands executed an do it manually

Comment: Have you looked into the server log? If not do so and maybe edit the question :-)